# What is the correct way to add pandas/scikit-learn packages to your project for use in AWS lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-ec2, scikit-learn, aws-lambda

I am doing all the steps that are mentioned in the following document:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

I am usign amazon's ec2 with amazon linux on it to build the package.

I also tried doing steps that are mentioned in 
https://markn.ca/2015/10/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/

Following is the error i get when the package is uploaded to AWS lambda and run:

```
START RequestId: cbfe0762-8f1b-11e5-9a1d-49fb4d3a0d13 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'test': No module named pandas

END RequestId: cbfe0762-8f1b-11e5-9a1d-49fb4d3a0d13
REPORT RequestId: cbfe0762-8f1b-11e5-9a1d-49fb4d3a0d13  Duration: 0.35 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 23 MB
```

The error doesn't give any specific indication.

Edit with more details:

Hi @maxymoo

I am just creating the zip of the contents. Not the folder that holds the .py file. When i try to add "requests" package with my .py file it works fine. Now when i try to add "pandas" package with my .py file then it gives me the above error.

Following are the steps that i am following:

1. Connect to ec2 with amazon linux running it.
2. start virtualenv
3. install pandas using "pip install pandas"
4. go to "/home/ec2-user/t1/lib/python2.7/site-packages" directory
5. take all the contents of "/home/ec2-user/t1/lib/python2.7/site-packages" add my test.py file to it and create the zip file
6. upload the zip file to amazon lambda
7. Run test

I get the following error:

```
START RequestId: feee67de-8f2f-11e5-bc34-bd42a1d7326b Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'test': No module named pandas

END RequestId: feee67de-8f2f-11e5-bc34-bd42a1d7326b
REPORT RequestId: feee67de-8f2f-11e5-bc34-bd42a1d7326b  Duration: 0.34 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 29 MB
```

The contents of test.py is:

```
import json

import requests

import pandas as pd


print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])

    print("value2 = " + event['key2'])

    print("value3 = " + event['key3'])

    return event['key1']  # Echo back the first key value

    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

Following are the files in the zip file:

```
drwxrwxr-x  52 pds  staff     1768 Nov 19 17:09 setuptools

drwxrwxr-x  32 pds  staff     1088 Nov 19 17:09 requests

drwxrwxr-x  34 pds  staff     1156 Nov 19 17:10 pip

drwxrwxr-x  11 pds  staff      374 Nov 19 17:10 setuptools-12.0.5.dist-info

drwxrwxr-x  10 pds  staff      340 Nov 19 17:10 pip-6.0.8.dist-info

drwxrwxr-x   8 pds  staff      272 Nov 19 17:10 requests-2.8.1.dist-info

drwxrwxr-x   6 pds  staff      204 Nov 19 17:10 pkg_resources

drwxrwxr-x   6 pds  staff      204 Nov 19 17:10 _markerlib

-rw-r--r--@  1 pds  staff      374 Nov 19 17:15 test.py

-rw-r--r--   1 pds  staff  3912745 Nov 19 17:16 Archive.zip

-rw-r--r--   1 pds  staff      315 Nov 19 18:09 easy_install.pyc

drwxrwxr-x   9 pds  staff      306 Nov 19 18:09 pytz-2015.7.dist-info

-rw-r--r--   1 pds  staff    30098 Nov 19 18:10 six.py

-rw-r--r--   1 pds  staff      126 Nov 19 18:10 easy_install.py

drwxrwxr-x   8 pds  staff      272 Nov 19 18:11 six-1.10.0.dist-info

drwxrwxr-x  15 pds  staff      510 Nov 19 18:11 pytz

drwxrwxr-x   9 pds  staff      306 Nov 19 18:11 python_dateutil-2.4.2.dist-info

-rw-r--r--   1 pds  staff    29545 Nov 19 18:11 six.pyc

drwxrwxr-x  17 pds  staff      578 Nov 19 18:11 dateutil
```

Comment: what's your directory structure? did you accidently zip the project folder itself rather than just the content of the folder?

Comment: Hi @maxymoo i have added the relevant details to the question itself. I just zipped the files under the main directory. The contents of the zip file are mentioned in the question. There was restriction of character in the comment so i edited the question.